# How to get the count of all records in a database table using a ViewBag?

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I'm trying to get the count of all records in a table using a viewbag using and then display that in the view. For some reason this doesn't display anything.

**Controller**

```
ViewBag.Users = db.Forum.Count();
```

**View**

```
@ViewBag.Users
```

Comment: This should work, have you verified `Count()` doesn't return `null`?

Comment: I'm rendering it as a partial view.. that has something to do with it. I'm creating a new model when I do it.   @{Html.RenderPartial("Info", new GamingQuest.Models.Forum());  }

Comment: I believe it is your use of the new Model in your RenderPartial method that is causing the issue.  First, if you render `@ViewBag.Users` on your main view, does it work?  Second, if you are going to render a partial from a primary view, then make what you are going to render in that partial part of your primary view model.  `@Html.Partial("Info", Model.InfoProperty)`.  Else, make a call to `@Html.RenderAction("Info")` to retrieve more information from the server if you do not want to add that information to your primary view model

Comment: You need to show more code.  Without anything else going on, what you have would work.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

`db.Forum.Select(g => g.id).Count();`

Replace **g.id** with your Forum Table Primary Key